# Update v-for loop based on a search therm on click

Tags: vuejs2, v-for

I am learning vuejs and I need to filter my v-for loop based on a search string triggered on click. I've seen many examples of filters using computed properties directly on the input but that doesn't suit me because I want to render to the view only the result(s) that match the criteria. Although this code shows the entire list by default, that's just for testing purposes, on the real application the user will select previously the desired category.

Vue script:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        produtos: [],
        busca: '',
        mostrar: 8,
        mostrarBase: 8,
        categoriaAtiva: ''
    },
    methods: {
        loadData: function() {
            this.$http
                .get('js/produtos.json')
                .then(function(res) {
                    this.produtos = res.data;
                });
        },
        buscar: function(busca) {
            console.log(this.busca)
        },
    mounted: function() {
        this.loadData();
    }
});
```

JSON Object:

```
[
    {
        "categoria": "chaveiro",
        "valor": 17.80,
        "itens": [
        {
            "nome": "Caveira",
            "numero": 4004
        },
        {
            "nome": "Coração Color",
            "numero": 4005
        },
        {
            "nome": "Coração Tribal",
            "numero": 4006
        },
        {
            "nome": "Bonfim",
            "numero": 4090
        }]
    },
    {
        "categoria": "tag",
        "valor": 13.20,
        "itens": [
            {
                "nome": "Árvore",
                "numero": 6001
            },
            {
                "nome": "Casa Color",
                "numero": 6002
            },
            {
                "nome": "Caveira",
                "numero": 6004
            },
            {
                "nome": "Coração Color",
                "numero": 6005
            }]
    },
    {
        "categoria": "tagcarro",
        "valor": 9.20,
        "itens": [
        {
            "nome": "Kombi",
            "numero": 8048
        },
        {
            "nome": "Viagem",
            "numero": 8050
        },
        {
            "nome": "Anjo da Guarda",
            "numero": 8061
        },
        {
            "nome": "Bússola",
            "numero": 8091
        }]
    },
    {
        "categoria": "necessaire",
        "valor": 19.90,
        "itens": [
        {
            "nome": "Frida",
            "numero": 9013
        },
        {
            "nome": "Olho' Grego",
            "numero": 9024
        },
        {
            "nome": "Kombi",
            "numero": 9048
        },
        {
            "nome": "Unicórnio",
            "numero": 9075
        }]
    }
]
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vue</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:300,300i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>

<body>
    <main id="app">
        <div class="w1200">
            <form v-on:submit.prevent="buscar">
                <input type="text" v-model="busca">
                <input type="submit" class="bt" value="buscar">
            </form>
            <header>
                <button class="bt" 
                        v-for="produto in produtos" 
                        @click="function(){ mostrar = mostrarBase, categoriaAtiva = produto.categoria }">
                        {{produto.categoria}}
                </button>
                <button class="bt" @click = "categoriaAtiva = ''">todas</button>
            </header>
            <div v-for="produto in produtos" v-if="produto.categoria === categoriaAtiva || categoriaAtiva==='' ">
                <h2>{{produto.categoria}} - R$ {{produto.valor.toFixed(2)}}</h2>
                <div v-if="produto.categoria === categoriaAtiva">
                    mostrando {{mostrar}} de {{produto.itens.length}}
                    <button v-if="mostrar >= (mostrarBase * 2)" class="bt" @click="mostrar -= mostrarBase">-</button>
                    <button v-if="mostrar < produto.itens.length" class="bt" @click="mostrar += mostrarBase">+</button>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li v-for="(item,index) in produto.itens" v-if="index < mostrar && produto.categoria === categoriaAtiva || categoriaAtiva===''">
                        {{item.nome}} | {{item.numero}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="js/vue-core.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vue-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vue-app1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
    "categoria": "chaveiro",
    "valor": 17.80,
    "itens": [{
        "nome": "Caveira",
        "numero": 4004
      },
      {
        "nome": "Coração Color",
        "numero": 4005
      },
      {
        "nome": "Coração Tribal",
        "numero": 4006
      },
      {
        "nome": "Bonfim",
        "numero": 4090
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "categoria": "tag",
    "valor": 13.20,
    "itens": [{
        "nome": "Árvore",
        "numero": 6001
      },
      {
        "nome": "Casa Color",
        "numero": 6002
      },
      {
        "nome": "Caveira",
        "numero": 6004
      },
      {
        "nome": "Coração Color",
        "numero": 6005
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "categoria": "tagcarro",
    "valor": 9.20,
    "itens": [{
        "nome": "Kombi",
        "numero": 8048
      },
      {
        "nome": "Viagem",
        "numero": 8050
      },
      {
        "nome": "Anjo da Guarda",
        "numero": 8061
      },
      {
        "nome": "Bússola",
        "numero": 8091
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "categoria": "necessaire",
    "valor": 19.90,
    "itens": [{
        "nome": "Frida",
        "numero": 9013
      },
      {
        "nome": "Olho' Grego",
        "numero": 9024
      },
      {
        "nome": "Kombi",
        "numero": 9048
      },
      {
        "nome": "Unicórnio",
        "numero": 9075
      }
    ]
  }
]


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    produtos: data,
    mostrar: 8,
    mostrarBase: 8,
    categoriaAtiva: null,
  },
  methods: {
//    loadData () {
//      this.$http
//        .get('js/produtos.json')
//        .then(function(res) {
//          this.produtos = res.data;
//        });
//    },
    buscar (busca) {
      console.log(this.busca)
    },
    toggle (category) {
      this.categoriaAtiva = category
    },
    reset () {
      this.categoriaAtiva = null
    },
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.loadData();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.5.1/vue-resource.min.js"></script>

<main id="app">
  <div class="w1200">
    <header>
      <button class="bt" v-for="(produto, index) in produtos" :key="index" @click="toggle(produto.categoria)">
        {{ produto.categoria }}
      </button>
      <button class="bt" @click="reset">todas</button>
    </header>

    <div v-for="produto in produtos">
      <div class="inner" v-if="produto.categoria === categoriaAtiva">
        <h2>{{produto.categoria}} - R$ {{produto.valor.toFixed(2)}}</h2>
        <div>mostrando {{mostrar}} de {{produto.itens.length}}</div>
        <div>
          <button v-if="mostrar >= (mostrarBase * 2)" class="bt" @click="mostrar -= mostrarBase">-</button>
          <button v-if="mostrar < produto.itens.length" class="bt" @click="mostrar += mostrarBase">+</button>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="(item, index) in produto.itens">
            {{item.nome}} | {{item.numero}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</main>
```

UPD!

Comment: Run it like a snippet

Comment: <script src="js/vue-core.js"></script> === <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script src="js/vue-resource.js"></script> === https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.5.1/vue-resource.js

//that's the vue script that I posted 
<script src="js/vue-app1.js"></script>

Comment: You shouldn't use vue-resource. Try axios instead.

Comment: UPD, please check it out. But actually it is the wrong way - to do like so!

Comment: The inspiration of this code came from a course on udemy, I disagree that vue-resource has anything to do with the question that I asked.

Comment: I talking not about vue resource, but about interaction of loops and conditions. Also it is better to use English language for this site sharedcode